# Why can I use a class without including the other file where it's defined in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin for wordpress, in my plugin I have 2 PHP files:
A.php and B.php

B.php is just a simple class, contains only something like `<?php class MyClass{...}`
and A.php is using an instance of that class in a function:

```
<?php function somFunc(){
 $var1 = new MyClass();
 $var1.doSomething();
}
```

Until now, A.php was containing in someFunc() `include 'b.php';` and I just removed it and it's still working. So I read about scopes in php and understood that unless I'm using namespaces, a file can't see the content of another without including.

So how is it still working? I really don't get it, is Wordpress doing something about it?

Comment: First of all, you should 'include' (I prefer 'require_once') in the A.php file outside the function (as you mentioned - scopes issue).

If you remove the 'include b.php' from your a.php file there is no way the function can work since it doesn't have your class defined.

Comment: Or it's just Wordpress doing that stuff for you so you don't have to worry about `include` or `require`.

Comment: @Oen44 hey mate, are you asking, or saying? :)

Comment: you can have multiple include statements, maybe the file is already included somewhere else in the codebase.

Comment: Add a `print` into the file and you will see if it gets loaded. Or even better: [stack trace it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php)

Comment: There could also be an auto-loader in place

Comment: @wp42 Just saying, try to find something in WP documentation.

Comment: Well, I find nothing about it. hope someone knows..